# Sass maths operators with functions

Tags: sass

I've got this function:

```
@function toRem($val){
    @return #{$val / $fontSize}rem;
}
```

And also this property but it compiled badly:

```
top: 3.5rem + toRem(15); --> 3.5rem0.9375rem (compiled)
```

I have tried with this as well but doesn't work either, the result is the same:

```
top: #{$headerHeight + toRem(15)};
```

But if I remove the function it works:

```
top: 3.5rem + 0.9375rem; --> 4.4375rem
```

Is not possible to do this or I am doing something wrong? Can't find any info about functions in math operators :S

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SASS, `#{}` is used for [interpolation](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).

In your case, the interpolation syntax around the variables is the reason why you were seeing the resulting value get concatenated like: `3.5rem0.9375`.

To work around this, you could evaluate the math expression as you normally would, without interpolation, and then add `0rem` in order to coerce the number into a `rem` unit:

```
@function toRem($val){
  @return ($val / $fontSize) + 0rem;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$fontSize: 16;

@function toRem($val){
  @return ($val / $fontSize) + 0rem;
}

element {
  top: toRem(32);
  left: 3.5rem + toRem(15);
}
```

Output:

```
element {
  top: 2rem;
  left: 4.4375rem;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks mate